Carpet Replacement Questions
We are having some carpet replaced and have questions:
1. What is this block in the closet?
The bedroom where this is being replaced has some weird issues. One is a piece of wooden blocking in the center of the closet doors. The closet doors have been replaced, so I assume this is part of the original doors since it appears to fall perfectly in the middle of the doorway.
The previous carpet and padding was cut around it, and it appears to be adhered with glue. Should I remove that blocking before new carpet is installed?


2. My floor doesn't feel level
It feels like a ridge in the room. I ripped back the existing carpet to check the state of the subfloor. It seems like its in good condition - I even jumped on it to check if it was still solid and it all seemed fine. It seems to start at a ridge where two pieces of plywood meet and slopes downward toward the wall.

More photos
Should I investigate more or just live with the fact that this floor isn't quite even? Its just a guest bedroom so I'm not too worried about it getting in the way.
Thanks in advance!

Does the hump in the floor occur on the sheet without the joint?

It does, but not as badly.
Sorry about my bad etiquette. Should I remove one question and ask it in a new post? I don't see anything about that in the help center. Which is the subjective question?

Looks to me like the ridge is at the butt joint and that the subfloor has sagged here, on either side of the joint.

I have no idea what that block is. Its location corresponds to where a guide would be for bipass doors, but you have bifold doors, so it's apparently useless. I'd take it out. It doesn't look critical to anything and could easily be replaced if you find a purpose later.
The hump in the floor is due to either poor carpentry, decay in the framing or swelling of the OSB sheet due to moisture at some point in the past, or settling of the foundation. Whether you correct that before carpet is entirely up to you. I'd want to know the situation. Resolution may be as simple as taking a belt sander to that joint to flatten it out a bit.
